# Calling python from c# using pythonnet

Tags: python, .net, python.net

I installed pythonnet in c# directly using NuGet, but setting runtime. PythonDLL shows that this field is read-only and cannot be changed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQJYi.png)

But pythonnet requires runtime. PythonDLL to be set
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgjd1.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try calling PythonDll by specifying the location paths in advance in this way:

```
string pythonRepos = @"Python39\";
string pythobLib = @"Python39\Lib\site-packages\";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pythonRepos, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", pythonRepos, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", pythobLib, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Maybe this will solve your problem.